# KeyBindings not registering during "run()" loop

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, key-bindings, awtrobot

I'm close to finishing what I've started, but I just can't manage to get my keybindings to work. When I press <kbd>w</kbd> it works just fine. But while the loop (auto clicker) is running (from pressing the JButton), the key binds don't register and I can't get it to do anything. I want the action for the <kbd>w</kbd> key to make to loop stop but the keybindings go out of focus and the loop just keeps running until I terminate it by pressing command <kbd>q</kbd>.

```
package autoclicker;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class click 
implements ActionListener{

    JFrame frame;
    JLabel label;
    JButton button;
    Action ON;
    Action OFF;
    private static Robot bot;

    public static boolean status = false;
    
    click(){
        
        ON = new statusON();

        //setting up JFrame
        frame = new JFrame("Bullet Chicken Clicker");
        label = new JLabel();
        button = new JButton("turn on?");
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLocation(600, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.add(button); 
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
        button.setOpaque(true);
        button.setForeground(Color.BLACK);   
        button.setBounds(125, 150, 150, 30);
        button.setVisible(true);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        button.setFocusable(false);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            
        label.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('w'), "forward");
        label.getActionMap().put("forward", ON);
    }
        
    //main action
    public void run(){
        try {
            bot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e2) {
            
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        if(status != false);
        while (status == true) {
            try {
                bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                bot.delay(1);
                bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                bot.delay(1);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (status == false) {
                status = false;
            break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public class statusON extends AbstractAction{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            status = false;
            System.out.print(status);
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
        status = true;
        System.out.print(status);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            run();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to move your bot into a separate thread. The loop is currently demanding all of the current thread's execution, so it's not able to execute the check for a user's input.

Comment: Found a good link of someone who is going for a similar setup:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24596936/is-there-a-way-to-stop-the-robot-class-after-it-has-started

Comment: What is the point of your "auto clicker". What is the point of having the mouse click every millisecond? You still haven't explained your requirement properly. If you are trying to do some kind of animation then you should be using a `Swing Timer`. The Swing tutorial has a section on Swing Timers. Also, class names should start with an  upper case character. Follow Java conventions when posting code to make it easier for us to read the code. What is the point of the label. You were told in your last question that is it not needed. Why should we continue to help when you ignore advice given?

Comment: @camickr The purpose of the auto mouse click can be discovered by the name of the JFrame. They're making a [Incremental Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_game). Most likely they're just at the phase where they are testing out some potential game mechanics.